# "Data and reference should be factors with same levels" with cross-validation on decision trees

Tags: r, decision-tree, cross-validation

Hope you re ok !

Since this morning I'm trying to fixe this error message : 
"Erreur : `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.".

I do not understand why, I already tried to use as.factor ...

Thank you in advance the community !

```
dataset <- as.factor(dataset)
set.seed(1)
train=sample(1:nrow(dataset), 92) #80%
dataset.test=dataset[-train,]
dataset.train=dataset[train,]

Classification.test=Classification[-train]
tree.dataset=tree(Classification~Age+BMI+Glucose+Insulin+HOMA+Leptin+Adiponectin+Resistin+MCP.1, data= dataset, subset=train)
summary(tree.dataset)
plot(tree.dataset)
text(tree.dataset, pretty = 0, cex=0.6)
tree.pred=predict(tree.dataset,dataset.test,type="class")
table(tree.pred, Classification.test) #68%

#cross validation 
set.seed(3)
cv.dataset=cv.tree(tree.dataset,FUN=prune.misclass)
plot(cv.dataset)
cv.dataset$dev
best.size <- cv.dataset$size[which(cv.dataset$dev==min(cv.dataset$dev))] # which size is better?
best.size
#reffiting
cv.dataset.pruned <- prune.misclass(tree.dataset, best=best.size)
summary(cv.dataset.pruned)
plot(cv.dataset.pruned)
text(prune.dataset,pretty=0,cex=0.8)


#plot(cv.dataset$size, cv.dataset$dev ,type="b") #inversement proportionnel

#prediction_tree <- predict(cv.dataset.pruned)
prediction_tree = predict(cv.dataset.pruned, newdata = dataset.test, type = "vector")

confusionMatrix(dataset_test, prediction_tree, treshold= 0.5, type = "tree")
```

Comment: sounds like you have levels present in your test data that aren't in your train data.

Comment: Levels? I do not understand, maybe I have to use as.factor